# Enable Synaptics Touchpad in Fedora 13

Tags: synaptics-touchpad, fedora-13

My Laptop is a Sony VAIO VPCS12C5E.
I recently installed Fedora 13 (x64).
I have the problem that the Touchpad is not working at all.
The following Synaptics driver is installed:

```
xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.2.2-6.fc13.x86_64
```

Touchpad is not listed in GPointing (Version 1.5.1-2)

A USB Mouse is working fine.

I tried adding the following configuration to a new X11 conf file under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-synaptics.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier      "touchpad catchall"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  Driver          "synaptics"
EndSection
```

I got the configuration from https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Input_device_configuration

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what kind of laptop you have. It's a long shot, but a lot of laptops have a key combination (Fn+F_) or other button that enables/disables the trackpad. Have you tried looking for something like that and pressing it?

Comment: Sorry forgot that: It's a Sony Vaio VPCS12C5E And there is no key that enables or disables the touchpad